# Display gnome-clocks timer on top bar/panel

Tags: gnome, gnome-clocks

I have installed gnome-clocks via apt. gnome-clocks has a timer function, which I would like to show on the top bar/panel. So when I start the timer It shows how many minutes are left for the timer on the top bar/panel.

I often create timer for tea, oven and stand up routine. It would be nice, If I could keep working on my desktop, while also knowing how far the timer has come without the need to reopen the window, over and over again.

I am running basic Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. No changed yet, fresh install.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Look for timer in extentions.gnome.org

Answer (score 0):

This feature isn't implemented, yet.

They have [an issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-clocks/-/issues/162) for something similar: displaying the timer on Notifications.

As @petep suggested, your best bet is looking into GNOME Extensions. For instance: [Simple Timer](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5115/simple-timer/) may fit your requirements (haven't tried it).